# FFmpeg doesn't recognize my audio sources

Tags: alsa, ffmpeg, pulseaudio

I want to record my screen with audio for practice.

I saw recommendations to use this command line:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -f x11grab -r 25 -s 800x600 -i :0.0+200,100 -c:a pcm_s16le -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 0 -threads 4 output.mkv
```

But `ffmpeg` doesn't recognize the "alsa" format or the "pulse" file. If I remove both of those, it can capture the specified region of the screen just fine, but silently.

I'm using Linux Mint 17 Mate edition; I know I'm using ALSA. My testing audio source is VLC (which I thought used PulseAudio) playing an Ogg Vorbis file from the system tray.

This is my `ffmpeg` configuration:

```
ffmpeg version 2.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul  6 2014 09:48:53 with Ubuntu clang version 3.4-1ubuntu3 (tags/RELEASE_34/final) (based on LLVM 3.4)
  configuration: --cc=clang --extra-libs=-ldl --disable-shared --disable-ffserver --enable-ffplay --disable-doc --enable-bzlib --enable-zlib --enable-libx264 --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libass --enable-libfaac --enable-libvpx --enable-libopus --enable-x11grab --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl
  libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
  libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
  libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
  libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
  libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswscale      2.  5.102 /  2.  5.102
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ALSA support isn't inherently built into `ffmpeg`. You need to have the ALSA development files installed at `./configure` time when building `ffmpeg`.

The `ffmpeg` configure script looks for `alsa/asoundlib.h` and `libasound`. If either is missing, it simply won't build ALSA support into the program.

This contrasts with other features of `ffmpeg` which you can enable with configure script flags. That is to say, you can't ask it *not* to build ALSA support in, if it finds the header and library files.